# Get the message id of provider by custom transport symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-mailer

I am using Symfony Custom Transport, and when I send mail with MailerInterface, as a result I am getting its own messageId.  However, I want to get the messageId of the provider, that I use in my Custom Transport(In my case it is Brevo). Also I

This is some code from my emailtransport.php

```
namespace Ngo\Project\NotifierBundle\Business\Engine\Transport\Email;

protected function doSendApi(SentMessage $sentMessage, Email $email, Envelope $envelope): ResponseInterface {    
$payLoad = $this->getPayload($email, $envelope);
    if(!empty($payLoad['campaignId'])) {
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', "https://api.brevo.com/v3/emailCampaigns/{$payLoad['campaignId']}/sendNow", [
            'headers' => [
                'accept' => 'application/json',
                'api-key' => $_ENV["EMAIL_API_KEY"],
            ],
        ]);
    }
    else{
        $body = json_encode($payLoad);
        $response = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://api.brevo.com/v3/smtp/email', [
            'body' => $body,
            'headers' => [
                'accept' => 'application/json',
                'api-key' => $_ENV['EMAIL_API_KEY'],
                'content-type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Also I have created my own service, in which I use send method of MailerInterface.

```
<?php

namespace Ngo\Project\NotifierBundle\Business\Engine;

use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Envelope;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\TransportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage;

class Emailer implements MailerInterface
{
    private TransportInterface $transport;

    private string $messageId;

    public function __construct(TransportInterface $transport)
    {
        $this->transport = $transport;
    }

    public function send(RawMessage $message, Envelope $envelope = null): void
    {
        $this->messageId = $this->transport->send($message)->getMessageId();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessageId(): string
    {
        return $this->messageId;
    }
}
```